# can't update a procedure in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I try to update a procedure in psql, the code gives no error:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.decrement_user_followers()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $function$ 
    BEGIN
      UPDATE users SET unit_followers = unit_followers - 1 WHERE id = OLD.user_id_followed;
      UPDATE users SET unit_following = unit_following - 1 WHERE id = OLD.user_id_follower;
    RETURN OLD;
    END $function$
```

But when I try to see the change `\df+ decrement_user_followers` gives me the old code.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for your question, didn't get any error but I just found what is wrong and solved my problem. The ";" is missing at the end ... ahhh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ";" was missing at the end ... ahhh

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.decrement_user_followers()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $function$ 
    BEGIN
      UPDATE users SET unit_followers = unit_followers - 1 WHERE id = OLD.user_id_followed;
      UPDATE users SET unit_following = unit_following - 1 WHERE id = OLD.user_id_follower;
    RETURN OLD;
    END $function$;
```